# KendoUI Upload control - Can't access server response in complete callback

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I'm trying to use the KendoUI file upload widget. The upload is working and the server is returning a valid JSON object but I cannot access the response data.

The docs say I should check e.XMLHttpRequest but this property is always undefined. In fact I can't access the e.files either.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] - Found the problem. I was using the complete callback, not success

*facepalm*

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to access response data, and perhaps a sample of the JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using the complete callback, not the success callback.

My bad. Carry on. There is nothing to see here...